# Numbers in flutter web vs flutter mobile

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a field in firebase that I store numbers in (can be `double` or `int`),

When I read this number and I assign it to function with parameter of `double` like this:

```
Function someFunction(double x)
{
  //some content
}
```

it works just fine on the web whether the value is `int` or `double`, but when I try the same code on mobile, it gives a type error saying that `int` is not a subtype of `double`.

So I am wondering, what is the difference that happened here between flutter mobile and flutter web.

Comment: I didn't run my projects on web before, does flutter use javascript on web. it maybe related with javascript which is not a type safety language.

Answer (score 0):

```
factory Animal.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Animal(
      id: map['id'] as String,
      name: map['name'] as String,
      dateBorn: map['dateBorn'].toDate(),
      gender: map['gender'] as String,
      father: map['father'] as String,
      mother: map['mother'] as String,
      raceFather: map['raceFather'] as String,
      raceMother: map['raceMother'] as String,
      percentageFather: map['percentageFather'] as String,
      percentageMother: map['percentageMother'] as String,
      animalTypeProduction: map['animalTypeProduction'] as String,
      animalStage: map['animalStage'] as String,
      weightBorn: **double.parse('${map['weightBorn']}'),
      weightWeaning: double.parse('${map['weightWeaning']}'),
      weightYear: double.parse('${map['weightYear']}'),**
      color1: map['color1'] as String,
      color2: map['color2'] as String,
      observations: map['observations'] as String,
      type: map['type'] as String,
      img: map['img'] as String,
    );
  }
```

That same error happened to me, and to solve it, I convert the number that comes from firebase to a string and then to a double and it is shown without error,
`double.parse('${map['${firebaseNum'}]}')`